# use of multiple <include /> tags in layout with ButterKnife

Tags: android, butterknife

I have a layout where I include the same sub-layout multiple times, each one with a different role:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/settings_eco_seekarc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/settings_arc" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/settings_comfort_seekarc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/settings_arc" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It works if I find the views in this way:

```
View eco = root.findViewById(R.id.settings_eco_seekarc);
mEcoSeekArc = (SeekArc) eco.findViewById(R.id.settings_seekarc);
mEcoLeaf = (ImageView) eco.findViewById(R.id.settings_leaf_img);
mEcoText = (TextView) eco.findViewById(R.id.settings_text);
View cmf = root.findViewById(R.id.settings_comfort_seekarc);
mComfortSeekArc = (SeekArc) cmf.findViewById(R.id.settings_seekarc);
mComfortLeaf = (ImageView) cmf.findViewById(R.id.settings_leaf_img);
mComfortText = (TextView) cmf.findViewById(R.id.settings_text);
```

I am introducing ButterKnife in my project now, and I hoped I could simply annotate each view (the following obviously doesn't work, and I can see why) and inject them later using each included layout root:

```
@InjectView(R.id.settings_seekarc)
SeekArc mEcoSeekArc;
@InjectView(R.id.settings_leaf_img)
ImageView mEcoLeaf;
@InjectView(R.id.settings_text)
TextView mEcoText;
@InjectView(R.id.settings_seekarc)
SeekArc mComfortSeekArc;
@InjectView(R.id.settings_leaf_img)
ImageView mComfortLeaf;
@InjectView(R.id.settings_text)
TextView mComfortText;

//then later...
View eco = root.findViewById(R.id.settings_eco_seekarc);
ButterKnife.inject(this, eco);
View cmf = root.findViewById(R.id.settings_comfort_seekarc);
ButterKnife.inject(this, cmf);
```

Doing it in this way, though, leads me to this error at the second injection:

> Error:(81, 13) error: Attempt to use @InjectView for an already
>   injected ID 2131493185 on 'mEcoSeekArc'.

My question is: is there a way to use ButterKnife in this scenario?

Answer (score 9):

you could use some type of sub-container like this:

```
public static class SettingsArcLayout {
  @InjectView(R.id.settings_text) public TextView mEcoText;
  @InjectView(R.id.settings_leaf_img) public ImageView mComfortLeaf;
  // etc...
}
```

then you have it

```
SettingsArcLayout layout1 = new SettingsArcLayout();
SettingsArcLayout layout2 = new SettingsArcLayout();
```

and then:

```
ButterKnife.inject(this); // inject eco and cmf
ButterKnife.inject(layout1, eco);
ButterKnife.inject(layout2, cmf);
```

and throught this class you can use:

```
layout1.mEcoText.setText(... etc
```

Comment: in this way it kind of defeats the purpose of using the <include/> tag, though...

Comment: I agree it's not so ideal and automatic as it should be, I'm just finding a workaround your problems. But you're still writing less code, more modular code and you still can use the ButterKnifeZelezny plugin (https://github.com/avast/android-butterknife-zelezny) to generate this sub container automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of my answer is the same as Budius proposed, I found it in a related issue on ButterKnife's [github repo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/393). Original Author is TomazMartins

The MainActivity:

```
public MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // 1. First, we declare the layout that was included as a View objects.
    @BindView(R.id.layout_1) View layout_1;
    @BindView(R.id.layout_2) View layout_2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // 2. In here, we bind the included layouts
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        // 4. Then, we create objects of the type of the IncludedLayout.
        //      In this example the layout reuse the same layout twice, so, there are two
        //      IncludedLayouts.
        IncludedLayout includedLayout_1 = new IncludedLayout();
        IncludedLayout includedLayout_2 = new IncludedLayout();

        // 5. We bind the elements of the included layouts.
        ButerKnife.bind(includedLayout_1, layout_1);
        ButerKnife.bind(includedLayout_2, layout_2);

        // 6. And, finally, we use them.
        includedLayout_1.displayed_text.setText("Hello");
        includedLayout_2.displayed_text.setText("Hey!");
    }

    // 3. We create a static class that will be an container of the elements
    //     of the included layout. In here we declare the components that
    //     hold this. In this example, there is only one TextView.
    static class IncludedLayout {
        @BindView(R.id.displayed_text) TextView displayed_text;
    }
}
```

The XML of the MainAcitvity:

```
<!--...-->
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include android:id="@+id/layout_1" layout="@layout/included_layout" />
        <include android:id="@+id/layout_2" layout="@layout/included_layout" />
</LinearLayout>
<!--...-->
```

The XML of the Included Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/displayed_text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

That's it!

When i ran it, although the id was the same, because I reused it, the text in the TextView was different.